# Set the Android alarm 2 hours before Fajr time (First prayer in Islam)

Tags: java, android

How to set the android alarm 2 hours before [fajr time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fajr_prayer):

```
if(cal_alarm(fajr_time)){ 
    cal_alarm.add(Calendar.DATE,2);
}
//SET YOUR AlarmManager here
```

Comment: Please include some details.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` and not `Calendar.DATE`:

> How to set the android alarm 2 hours before fajr time

Your code can look like this:

```
int twoHoursBefore = fajr_time - 2;
cal_alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, twoHoursBefore);
```

Comment: can you provide me the full code to Set the Android alarm 2 hours before Fajr time